# MergZXing GetBarcode() captures barcode but Cancel and ! Buttons do not, any workaround?

Tags: ios, livecode

I'm using LiveCode 8.0 Indy

I have the MergEXT that is bundled with LiveCode, and am using the MergZXingGetBarcode() Method.

The method correctly displays the control, and will capture a barcode, however if I try to press Cancel or !, nothing appears until AFTER the control has successfully captured a barcode.

I suspect in the background, it is displaying the results of these actions, any way for me to catch this and close the control?

Or maybe hide those buttons?

Here is the code I'm using (from Sample App)

```
on mouseUp
   try
      put mergZXingGetBarcode() into fld 1
   catch e
      put e
   end try
end mouseUp
```

Thank you

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please report it [here](http://quality.liveocde.com)
FYI the barcode scanner in mergAV has considerably better performance and as the ZXing library is no longer maintained for iOS I usually encourage people in that direction. It does mean you need to create your own UI for scanning though.

Comment: Thank you, I'll pursue the MergeAV route.  Thanks for your quick advice!

Answer (score 0):

"This sounds like a bug. Please report it here FYI the barcode scanner in mergAV has considerably better performance and as the ZXing library is no longer maintained for iOS I usually encourage people in that direction. It does mean you need to create your own UI for scanning though." – Monte Goulding

This answer was taken from the comments, this seemed like the best way to mark as answered.